# Convert PPT into JPG/PNG on windows

Tags: vbscript, jpeg, converters, powerpoint

I would like to convert a ppt presentation in a collection of images, one per each slide, programmatically in a windows environment.

I tried to modify the following code that transform a ppt to a pdf(perfectly working) but I        dind't succed. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

```
Option Explicit

Sub WriteLine ( strLine )
    WScript.Stdout.WriteLine strLine
End Sub

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa432714(v=office.12).aspx
Const msoFalse = 0   ' False.
Const msoTrue = -1   ' True.

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb265636(v=office.12).aspx
Const ppFixedFormatIntentScreen = 1 ' Intent is to view exported file on screen.
Const ppFixedFormatIntentPrint = 2  ' Intent is to print exported file.

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746754.aspx
Const ppFixedFormatTypeXPS = 1  ' XPS format
Const ppFixedFormatTypePDF = 2  ' PDF format

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744564.aspx
Const ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst = 1   ' Slides are ordered vertically, with the first slide in the upper-left corner and the second slide below it.
Const ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst = 2 ' Slides are ordered horizontally, with the first slide in the upper-left corner and the second slide to the right of it.

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744185.aspx
Const ppPrintOutputSlides = 1               ' Slides
Const ppPrintOutputTwoSlideHandouts = 2     ' Two Slide Handouts
Const ppPrintOutputThreeSlideHandouts = 3   ' Three Slide Handouts
Const ppPrintOutputSixSlideHandouts = 4     ' Six Slide Handouts
Const ppPrintOutputNotesPages = 5           ' Notes Pages
Const ppPrintOutputOutline = 6              ' Outline
Const ppPrintOutputBuildSlides = 7          ' Build Slides
Const ppPrintOutputFourSlideHandouts = 8    ' Four Slide Handouts
Const ppPrintOutputNineSlideHandouts = 9    ' Nine Slide Handouts
Const ppPrintOutputOneSlideHandouts = 10    ' Single Slide Handouts

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745585.aspx
Const ppPrintAll = 1            ' Print all slides in the presentation.
Const ppPrintSelection = 2      ' Print a selection of slides.
Const ppPrintCurrent = 3        ' Print the current slide from the presentation.
Const ppPrintSlideRange = 4     ' Print a range of slides.
Const ppPrintNamedSlideShow = 5 ' Print a named slideshow.

' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744228.aspx
Const ppShowAll = 1             ' Show all.
Const ppShowNamedSlideShow = 3  ' Show named slideshow.
Const ppShowSlideRange = 2      ' Show slide range.

'
' This is the actual script
'

Dim inputFile
Dim outputFile
Dim objPPT
Dim objPresentation
Dim objPrintOptions
Dim objFso

If WScript.Arguments.Count <> 2 Then
    WriteLine "You need to specify input and output files."
    WScript.Quit
End If

inputFile = WScript.Arguments(0)
outputFile = WScript.Arguments(1)

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not objFso.FileExists( inputFile ) Then
    WriteLine "Unable to find your input file " & inputFile
    WScript.Quit
End If

If objFso.FileExists( outputFile ) Then
    WriteLine "Your output file (' & outputFile & ') already exists!"
    WScript.Quit
End If

WriteLine "Input File:  " & inputFile
WriteLine "Output File: " & outputFile

Set objPPT = CreateObject( "PowerPoint.Application" )

objPPT.Visible = True
objPPT.Presentations.Open inputFile

Set objPresentation = objPPT.ActivePresentation
Set objPrintOptions = objPresentation.PrintOptions

objPrintOptions.Ranges.Add 1,objPresentation.Slides.Count
objPrintOptions.RangeType = ppShowAll

' Reference for this at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746080.aspx
objPresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat outputFile, ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, msoTrue, ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst, ppPrintOutputSlides, msoFalse, objPrintOptions.Ranges(1), ppPrintAll, "Slideshow Name", False, False, False, False, False

objPresentation.Close
ObjPPT.Quit
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use .ExportAsFixedFormat.  Instead, either use .SaveAs or use the .Export method on each slide.

.Export gives you far more control.  In VBA, you'd do like so:

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim lWidthInPixels As Long
Dim lHeightInPixels As Long

lWidthInPixels = 1024
lHeightInPixels = 768

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    oSl.Export "c:\path\myfile" & Format(oSl.SlideIndex, "0000") & ".jpg", _
        "JPG", _
        lWidthInPixels, _
        lHeightInPixels
Next
```

Comment: Hello guys, I know some time passed, but I tried to merge the two codes, and I failed (my ignorance in VBS is pretty big).

Would you mind sharing the full script if it worked? @user3664364 ?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to merge the two code examples?  One saves PDFs, the other saves JPGs. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @SteveRindsberg I was trying to "merge" or at least use the two of them as source because of being deeply ignorant in VBS basically (took me a day just to figure out that VBS and VBA are two different things, that shows the foundations I have in the topic)

What I am trying to learn is how to write a script that with a double click (i basically need a companion script to prepare the data for a client app) picks some folders structure, searches it for pptx files, and then converts them all into png images into another fixed folder structure (where my main app will read them)

Comment: @drHogan OK, understood.  I'd start by letting us know whether you want this to run from within PPT or as an external script (the latter, I'm guessing).  That'd point you at VBA or VBS respectively.

Comment: yep, definitely the latter. so VBS would be the way right? What I had some problem with about VBS is that most of the powerpoint-specific examples i found were VBA and didn't seem to work in VBS, that is why I can't seem to find a way through it yet. Also, another friend suggested PowerShell, would that make sense to your knowledge as an alternative to VB?

Comment: I'd go with VBS, if only because it bears a close(-ish) resemblance to VB/VBA and there are loads of VBA examples of PPT code out there.  It looks like my friend Shyam Pillai has an example to get you started:  http://skp.mvps.org/vb/vbppt002.htm

Comment: thank you very much, it feels like the fog of my ignorance is slowly starting to fade. I had tried that script already, but it seemed to give me an error every time I tried it, I will do it again. 
As a quick idea, not sure if it makes sense, would you deem it a decent process to write a VBA macro for powerpoint (as it seems to have some more control over Ppt) and then execute all the batching and folders management from a vbs script also calling that macro?

Comment: EDIT : apparently I had done smth wrong, because this time it worked. Thanks, I will work on it and see what I achieve. Thanks again Steve!

Comment: >>  would you deem it a decent process to write a VBA macro for powerpoint  Assuming you can invoke a PPT macro from VBS (you can from VB, so I imagine so), that's how I'd approach it, actually. Lots better debugging tools in VBA's editor.

Comment: hi @SteveRindsberg, just wanted to thank you for the help, in the end though I went for a way i knew better and wrote the whole thing as a c# application (basically i process a set of pptx to png, copy them over a folder structure, and also need to process some videos to extract the thumbnail). Took me less than half a day and works like a charm.

Comment: @drHogan Bingo!  Glad it's all working well for you then.