# Save powerpoint presentation as image, custom picture file name.

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Using vba I want to save the presentation as png image. For that I use the following code line:

```
ActivePresentation.SaveAs myLocation, ppSaveAsPNG, msoTrue
```

This is the easy part, here comes what I want to know. For example if you are using an english powerpoint version, the images will be called Slide1.png, Slide2.png... but if the language is in spanish it will be Diapositiva1.png, Diapositiva2.png. After I create the images I need to work with them in VBA so I need to know what name they will have in order to copy or reference them. How can I set a custom name for them?

Or is there a list of the possible name that they can have depending on the language of the powerpoint?

Comment: Are there any other files in `myLocation` path? If not, you could certainly write a little bit of code to rename them individually. Even if there are other files, you could use the file properties with a `FileSystemObject` to rename all of the PNG files that were, for example, created in the last 1 minute (should be reasonably safe, assuming nobody else is writing to that same location).

Comment: Also see here for how to get the language ID: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8588756/1467082  you could use that and construct a hash table/Enum to work with as many languages as you anticipate.  If you know the language ID, then you know the language, and from that just translate "Slide" and build your hash table that way. You would need to modify the code if "new" languages are encountered, but assuming you are only working with a handful of regular languages, this should be a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here.  Instead of SaveAs, use Slide.Export ... gives you much better control over the range of images exported, how they're named and the resolution of the exported images.

[Convert PPT into JPG/PNG on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955260/convert-ppt-into-jpg-png-on-windows)