# Save PPT into various folders as various file types using VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am searching for some VBA code i could run to do the following:

I have a Powerpoint slide (1 slide only) that needs to be saved into 3 different locations as 3 different file types:

Saved as file1.pdf into c:\folder1
Saved as file2.ppt into c:\folder2
saved as file3.png into c:\folder3

Is this possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Rob.

Comment: Yes its possible, but try searching before posting. Combine [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/PowerPoint-VBA/articles/presentation-saveas-method-powerpoint) and [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/powerpoint-vba-save-presentation-as-pdf-in-same-folder) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23956356/1726522).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Private Sub ExportFiles()
    Dim lWidthInPixels As Long
    Dim lHeightInPixels As Long

    lWidthInPixels = 1024
    lHeightInPixels = 768

    'pdf
    ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat "c:\folder1\file1.pdf", _
    ppFixedFormatTypePDF, ppFixedFormatIntentPrint, msoCTrue, ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst, _
    ppPrintOutputSlides, msoFalse, , ppPrintAll, , False, False, False, False, False

    'ppt
    Application.ActivePresentation.SaveCopyAs "c:\folder2\file2"

    'png
    Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Export "c:\folder3\file3.png", "png", lWidthInPixels, lHeightInPixels 

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks CMArg!  I had to add some code to set the height and width of the png file as it was publishing 1 pixel wide x 720pixels tall.

Comment: See edited answer. Please accept if it fit your needs.

Comment: Works a treat.  Thanks!

Comment: Mark as accepted please..:) That's the way we say "thank you" in this site...